# jqGrid does not respond to hideCol method

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have an issue with the `hidecol` method of jqGrid. The method is called, but nothing happens.

I use version jqGrid **4.5**.

My table is created like so:

```
        // Create table with jqGrid
    $('#shipTable').jqGrid({ // set your grid id
        data : tableItems, // insert data from the data object we created above
        datatype : 'local',
        autowidth : true,
        colNames : [
                'Name', 'Status', 'Ownership', 'Monitoring', 'Shiptype', 'Departure', 'ETD', 'Destination', 'ETA', 'Delta', 'SOG', 'Speed', 'HFO', 'HFO LS', 'MDO', 'MDO LS', 'RPM 24/H', 'Prop slip 24/H', 'GW 24/H', 'Next service'
        ], // define column names
        colModel : [
                {
                    name : 'name',
                    index : 'name',
                    width : 160,
                    hidden:false
                }, {
                    name : 'status',
                    index : 'status',
                    width : 70
                }, //other cols left out for brevity
        ], // define column models
        rowNum : 100,
        height : 400,
        scrollOffset : 30,
        sortname : 'id', 
        viewrecords : true, 
        sortorder : 'desc', 
        gridview : true, 
        caption : 'Ships',
        pager : '#pager',
        toppager:true,
        ignoreCase : false,
        onSelectRow : function(rowid) {
            // some work
        }
    });
```

With jQuery I create a list of checkboxes which manage the visibility of the colums.

However as a test I now have all checkboxes call this:

```
$("#shipTable").jqGrid('hideCol',"Name").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

This should work, but for some reason it is not. I did some custom **CSS**, can that be it?

Any tips highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined column with low case name (`name : 'name'`), but used with first capital letter in the column name ("Name"). To fix the problem you need to use

```
$("#shipTable").jqGrid("hideCol", "name");
```

instead of

```
$("#shipTable").jqGrid('hideCol',"Name").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: I was in the understanding that I needed to use the column name. From the documetation: "Given a single colname, it hides the column with that name." see: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Comment: But I've tried this (and i thought i tried it before) and it worked thanks!

Comment: @jorrebor: I think that your problem is that you use `autowidth: true` option which just set *initial* width of grid based on `innerWidth()` of outer container of the grid. You can call `setGridWidth` method of grid with `true` as the second parameter (`shrink`) *after* calling of `hideCol`. In the way you will recalculate the grid width and adjust width of all columns.

Comment: I solved it by getting the width of the container first and using this width after hiding the column in the setgridwidth method. I think it does the same thing, thanks anyway!